# Recycle view OnitemclickListener

Tags: android, view

How I can handle click of item RecycleView? 
I found way write in adapter in ViewHolder,
but how I can handle these same click in activity,

```
 public ViewHolder(View itemView) {         
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
```

And I tried

```
  AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener clickListener = new AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterViewCompat<?> adapterViewCompat, View view, int i, long l) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You click " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      }
  };
  recycleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You click now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          Log.i("Screen Two ", v.getVerticalScrollbarPosition() + "");
      }
  });
    recycleView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) clickListener);
  recycleView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          return false;
      }
  });
```

But they do not work, although in Activity
help me.

Comment: You should write it on ViewHolder.
do you want to put it on specific items ?

Comment: use `listView.setOnItemClickListener` and in `onItemClick` use `view.getTag()` to get your `ViewHolder`, and make sure you set holder to view in adapter class

Comment: you mean add onItemClick in    

recycleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You click now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          Log.i("Screen Two ", v.getVerticalScrollbarPosition() + "");
      }
  }); i so tried, but don't work

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi I don't understand You, Could you provide an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom listener for your adapter to propagate the click event to your activity. There is no such thing as `OnItemClickListener` in `RecyclerView`.

Comment: custom listener for adapter You mean 
 public ViewHolder(View itemView) {         
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
(sorry don't know so code format)

but I do action in activity

Comment: look at this example: http://venomvendor.blogspot.cz/2014/07/setting-onitemclicklistener-for-recycler-view.html

Comment: I did just broadcast receiver,
how think, so right?